# Rails - has_one and belongs_to for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have these two tables:

```
accounts
  - user_id

users
  - account_id
```

Many users can belong to an account and an account can have exactly one owner with full permissions.  If a user owns an account, the two should reference each other.  I'm trying to figure out how to set up this association.  Here's what I have:

```
class Account < AR::Base
  has_many :users
  has_one :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
```

This seems right to me, but the User class is definitely not:

```
class User < AR::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_one :account
```

An object can't belong to and have one at the same time.  How should I set up my User class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work I think:

```
class Account < AR::Base
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id


class User < AR::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_one :account, inverse_of: :owner
```

Comment: I don't think that solves it.  I'm getting this error now: `undefined method 'updated?' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::HasOneAssociation:0x00000108d76b40>`

Comment: I changed the has_one to `has_one :owned_account, class_name: 'Account', inverse_of: :owner`.  That fixed it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perfect! The `undefined method 'updated?'` is because of the duplicate association name; renaming it fixes the issue.